# Bias of a linear estimator, different results with different methods

Tags: estimation, econometrics, unbiased-estimator

Given the linear model:

$y=\beta x+\varepsilon $

an estimator for the slope was suggested:

$\widehat{\beta} =\frac{\sum y}{\sum x}$

I wish to determine if it is linear and if it is unbiased.

Clearly, it is linear, no problem here:

$\widehat{\beta}=\frac{1}{\sum x}\cdot y_{1}+\frac{1}{\sum x}\cdot y_{2}+...+\frac{1}{\sum x}\cdot y_{n}$

As for bias. I have calculated the expected value, and found that it is equal to the real slope, i.e., it is unbiased.

However, there is a proof saying that for linear estimators, an estimator is unbiased if the sum of all coefficients of y, is 0 (and the sum of the coefficients of y multiplied by x is 1).

Now,

$\frac{1}{\sum x} + \frac{1}{\sum x} + \frac{1}{\sum x} + ... + \frac{1}{\sum x}$

is not 0.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi: The proof statement doesn't sound correct. Could you provide the details ?